# How to save all values in memory, and use command to check them, just like debug in Matlab

Tags: java, c++, debugging, matlab, memory

I have been using Matlab for years and like the way debuging in it, all values are stored in memory, when you need check one, just type in command window.

However, in C++ and Java, those data not printed or given in console would not be able to see after execution. Is there some developing environment that can enable me to debug Java and C like Matlab?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 1):

I have been using Java for years.In java ide like IDEA,Eclipse,Netbeans,you can put a line breakpoint to see the values in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to debugging `mex` files (C++ compiled Matlab functions).

Even in your C/C++ modules, you can still access Matlab's environment (variables available from the command line). What I usually do is write temporary variables from the mex C code so I can later analyze the data and understand the inner working of the function.

The C function [mexPutVariable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/apiref/mexputvariable.html) may be used with the first argument "base" (or "caller") to create a Matlab array that is available from the command line after the mex has finished processing.